# RAISERROR raises substitution parameter error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

following T-Sql code:

```
DECLARE @usu VARCHAR(10);
SET @usu = 'TOM';
PRINT @usu;
RAISERROR ('Name of USU is %i ',14,2,@usu);
```

returns following error:

> Msg 2786, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 
>  The data type of substitution
>   parameter 1 does not match the expected type of the format
>   specification.

Does anyone know how I can get rid of this error?

Comment: I would stop doing what the error message is hinting at.

Comment: Any particular reason for choosing severity 14? Typically that is used for [insufficient permissions](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#severitylevels)

Comment: Please update the rather ironic title, of course RAISEERROR raises an error ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, change your format to `Name of USU is %s`, the `%i` means the value of `@usu` is a signed integer. All of the format types are clearly [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Try to change that:

```
RAISERROR ('Name of USU is %i ',14,2,@usu);
```

into that

```
RAISERROR ('Name of USU is %s ',14,2,@usu);
```

since @usu is varchar(10) and %i means signed integer

Answer (score 2):

try

```
DECLARE @usu VARCHAR(10);
SET @usu = 'TOM'; 
PRINT @usu; 
--modify this line  RAISERROR ('Name of USU is %i',14,2,@usu);
RAISERROR ('Name of USU is %s',14,2,@usu);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I missed the forest for the trees. -> so simple ;-)

Comment: Hi @TomStevens, if this is the answer please mark it as solution. Thanks.